# Typesetting single chapters in large book while preserving all cross-references, accurate page numbering, etc

Tags: tufte, preview

I'm writing a large book (using tufte-book) that will likely be 500 pages.  My computer has enough working memory that I can typeset the full text but this book is about art and the digital document includes many many large image files.  Working memory cannot hold the full book with all its images.  It *can* hold all the text and the images for just one or two (or possibly three) chapters.  But no more than that.

Just a single chapter--about half written--yields a pdf of nearly 100Mbytes.

Here's the structure of my LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\chapter*{My preface}

Here is my preface text.

\input{Chapter1.tex}
\input{Chapter2.tex}
...
\input{Chapter10.tex}

\bibliography{myBibliography}

\end{document}
```

I'm happy to digitally typeset the full book with the figures in only one chapter (e.g., Chapter 7), and then print a pdf of just that chapter (e.g., pages 350-400, or whatever).

The problem is that it is essential that the page numbering, inter-chapter cross-referencing, left-right page symmetry, etc. be proper on these pages, and that the table of contents, bibliography, index and so forth contain the material for the *full* book.

As such, the common approach of typesetting a single chapter at a time, without the other chapters, simply will not work.

I'm hoping there is a way to make some sort of figure-less (low-memory usage) preview version of each of the other chapters (where their preview images are of the proper size, to ensure the layout will match the final book) with a "full figure" version of just the target chapter (e.g., Chapter 7), so I can surmount these problems.

Is that possible?

I'm using TeXShop 3.96 under Mac OS 10.12.6.

Comment: You could alternate between two compilation modes: (a) full document (i.e., all chapters), but with `draft` mode enabled at the document class level -- this will create all cross-references, etc, but won't include any images and should thus work with your computer's resource constraints -- and (b) one chapter at a time, *without* the `draft` option, and with a suitable `\setcounter{page}{<num>}` directive to start at the correct page number?

Comment: Alternatively, assuming you're using pdfLaTeX to compile the document, have you tried switching to either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @Mico:  Interesting idea.  I'll try that later today.  It takes a bit of hand coding (consulting the typeset draft document to find page numbers to start chapters, etc.) but I'm desperate and will try anything!  I hope I don't have to switch everything to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex... I've always had annoying problems with that kind of system-level switching.  But will those versions permit what I seek?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - Depending on your computer's memory constraints, the approach I outlined might work with compiling 3 to 4 chapters "for real" during the "(b) phase" of the process, not just one chapter at a time.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - Which TeX distribution do you employ? TeXLive, MikTeX, or something else? How recently did you update the TeX distribution?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - TeXshop is a front-end, not a TeX distribution. Since your OS is MacOS 10.12 "Sierra", is it correct to assume that you employ MacTeX? If so, MacTeX2018 or something less recent? By the way, the most recent version of TeXshop is 4.27; if you're still using version 3.96, you should seriously consider performing an update.

Comment: @Mico:  I believe I'm using MacTeX2018.  But where are you headed with this?

Comment: `\include` is designed to exactly allow processing of individual chapters while keeping all cross references and numbering, however the omitted chapters really are omitted, it allows quicker drafting but you need to be able to process the full document at some point. (unless you patch together separate pdf files at the end)

Comment: if you showed your log file when it runs out of memory someone could probably tell you how to increase it, most fixed sizes in texlive/mactex are configurable in `texmf.cnf`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  "...you need to be able to process the full document at some point."  With all the image files included simultaneously?  I don't forsee that happening.  The set of image files so far total a few hundred gigabytes and there is no way I can have that much working memory.  But I'll work on your `\include` suggestion in the meantime.  Increasing working memory to hold the *full* book is out of the question... it is simply too large!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - Where I'm headed with these questions is this: I'm trying to figure out if your TeX distribution is of a sufficiently recent vintage that trying to use LuaLaTeX might make sense. LuaTeX used to be a serious memory hog, but this issue has receded of late. I thus recommend you try compiling the full document (without the `draft` option) under LuaLaTeX and see how far you get.

Comment: @Mico:  What is the functional benefit of using LuaLaTeX?  The fact that it might be memory efficient cannot help the fact that my images total hundreds of gigabytes (and I'm not done writing!).  Can it?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - If each chapter's file size is going to be in dozens, possibly hundreds, of gigabytes, how on earth are you going to distribute such a gargantuan document? (That's far more than most 8k-sampled movies...) Have you considered down-sampling the image files, from the hundreds-of-gigabytes range to the (still preposterously large) 10-20MByte range?

Comment: @Mico:  My plan is to create full camera-ready pdf, chapter-by-chapter, and upload them one-by-one to my publisher's internal server.  The end product is a book printed on paper.  Yes, of course I've down-sampled images to the extent possible... but that will not suffice.  Take a look at an art-history book to see the wealth of color images that such books demand!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork So it seems you *do* already intend to go along the "unless you patch together separate pdf files at the end" path from David Carlisle's comment that does not make processing the full document in non-draft mode.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:  Yes, at some level I will have to "patch together separate pdf files at the end."  So if David Carlisle's \include and \includeonly proposal will truly work, then perhaps problem solved!  (I'll try it as soon as I can.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork "My plan is to create full camera-ready pdf." I suggest you talk to the publisher and find out what *their* plan for dealing with such a PDF is. If they really are going to do ultra high resolution color printing, most likely they are going to strip the images out of the "camera ready PDF" anyway and process them differently from the text. In that case including them in the PDF was a waste of everybody's time and risks corrupting the original hi res image. You might just as well use low-res images for proofreading purposes and supply the high-res files separately.

Comment: … you had better be absolutely sure you and the publisher both agree on how to deal with ICC color profiles for example otherwise there are likely to be several "colour resampling" steps degrading the image quality.It would be remarkable if all the *original* scanned or photographed images even had the *same* color profile, unless they were all created for this single project....

Comment: @alephzero:  Thanks.  This is my third book with that particular major publisher, but I'll check with their production team next week.  I do want to have camera-ready document for teaching, feedback from scholars, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `include` system instead of `input`

```
\documentcslass{...}
\includeonly{chapter1}
 %\includeonly{chapter2} % and similar
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
% etc
\end{document}
```

GOM

Comment: PeterWilson:  Thanks, I just tried that (with several versions of `\includeonly` or just `\include` in the body of the document) and none typeset the desired chapter.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PeterWilson (and others):  I'm sorry but your proposed solution simply doesn't work for me.  I have tried all manner of typesetting with just the `includeonly`, mixtures, with or without additional chapters, and so on.  Has anyone else tried this proposed solution?  What am I missing!?

Comment: @PeterWilson:  Finally works!  It turns out (for some reason) that `\include{Chapter1.tex}` and `\includeonly{Chapter7.tex}` does not work, but \include{Chapter7} does (no .tex).  I don't know why this is the case, but at least now I know what to do! (accept)